# Pagination not working completely

Tags: php, pagination

I'm having problem making my pagination work though there is not error message that shows up it is still not working.

I suspect that there's something I have to do with this code. Help me please. TIA guys.

```
while($runrows=mysql_fetch_assoc($run, $limit))
```

Below is the code of the page

```
<?php

$connect = mysql_connect($m_Host,$m_User,$m_Pass) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<br />";

mysql_select_db($m_Db,$connect) or die(mysql_error());
error_reporting(error_reporting()&~E_NOTICE);

if(isset($_POST['search_query']))
{
$search_query=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['search_query']));
echo "<div class=\"searchText\"><br><b class='float'>Search the knowledgebase</b></div><br><hr />";

$search_query_x=explode(" ",$search_query);

    foreach($search_query_x as $search_each)
        {
            $x++;
            if($x==1)
            $construct.="Tags LIKE '%$search_each%'";
            else
            $construct.="AND Tags LIKE '%$search_each%'";
        }
$construct="SELECT * FROM knowledgebase WHERE $construct";
$run=mysql_query($construct);
$foundnum=mysql_num_rows($run);

    if($foundnum==0)
        {
            echo "Sorry, there is no matching result for your query: <i><b>$search_query</b></i><br /><br />
            1. Please check your spelling.<br />
            2. Try more general terms.<br />
            3. Please check broader alternatives like Google.<br />
            4. Contact your <b>Floorwalker</b> or <b>Process Analyst</b>.<br />
            5. If you found the solution to this scenario somewhere else, please advise your <b>Knowledge Manager</b>.";
        }

    else
        {
            echo "$foundnum result(s) found!<p>";
                while($runrows=mysql_fetch_assoc($run, $limit))
                {
                $Document_Title=$runrows['Document Title'];
                $URL=$runrows['URL'];
                $Target_Account=$runrows['Target Account'];
                $Modified=$runrows['Modified'];
                $Tags=$runrows['Tags'];
                echo"

                <div class='width: 400px'>
                <div class='Document Title'><a href='$URL' title='$Document_Title &#013$Target_Account &#013 $Modified &#013$Tags' target='_blank'>$Document_Title</a></div>
                <div class='Target Account'>
                    <b><font face='arial' size='1' color='Black'>Program:</font></b>
                        <font face='arial' size='1' color='Black'>$Target_Account</font></div>
                <div class='Keywords'>
                    <b><font face='arial' size='1' color='Black'>Keywords:</font></b>
                        <font face='arial' size='1' color='Black'>$Tags</font></div>
                </div>
                <br />
                ";
                }
        }
}
        else
            {
            echo"Found what you were looking for? If not, please consult your Process Analyst.";
            }

    //to make pagination
        require_once('config.php');
        include_once ('php\function.php');
        $page = (int) (!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]);
        $limit = 5;
        $startpoint = ($page * $limit) - $limit;
        $statement = "`knowledgebase` where `active` = 1";
?>

<?php
        echo pagination($statement,$limit,$page);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to be a little more specific about what your code does – you claim there's no error message, does that mean the above code produces an empty page? If so, that's most likely caused by the settings of your hosting provider and usually happens when any error occurs during the parsing and execution of your script. Try asking your provider if it's possible to have error reporting enabled and make sure to look around if there's not an error log file somewhere you can access.
It's hard to help you with the supplied information as you've shown us a lot of seemingly irrelevant code whilst concealing the source code you're having problems with (the pagination function). Are you sure the require_once and include_once functions don't error? Are the paths valid?

You might as well want to use the built-in `intval` function to parse $_GET page instead of using type casting:

```
    $page = isset($_GET["page"]) ? intval($_GET["page"]) : 1;
```

I also have some doubts about the part of your code that you claim isn't related to the problem you're encountering: I can't imagine the foreach loop producing a valid MySQL query as you don't separate the LIKE clauses from each other with whitespaces.

```
$search_query_x=explode(" ",$search_query);

foreach($search_query_x as $search_each)
{
    $x++;

    if($x==1) {
         //           v          the search clauses need to be separated by spaces
         $construct.=" Tags LIKE '%$search_each%'";
    } else {
         //           v          same here
         $construct.=" AND Tags LIKE '%$search_each%'";
    }
}

$run=mysql_query($construct); // it's also important to check if the returned query resource ($run) is valid - mysql_query returns FALSE on failure
if ($run === false) {
    echo "MySQL query failed! Error #" . mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

$foundnum=mysql_num_rows($run);
```